# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error by ora_sql_txt(ora_name_list_t)

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

table:

```
create table EMPLOYEES_LOG
(
  who    VARCHAR2(300),
  when   DATE,
  action VARCHAR2(2000)
)
```

trigger:

```
create or replace trigger aiud_employees_copy
  after insert or update or delete
  on employees_copy 
declare
    l_action employees_log.action%type;
    l_sql_text ora_name_list_t;
begin
    l_action := 'The statement that causes the change was:' || chr(10);

    for i in 1..ora_sql_txt(l_sql_text) loop
        l_action := l_action || l_sql_text(i);
    end loop;
    insert into employees_log(who, action, when)
        values(user, l_action, sysdate);
end aiud_employees_copy;
```

execute:

```
update employees_copy set salary=salary*1.05 where department_id=20;
```

gives me the error:

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error at  **for i in 1..ora_sql_txt(l_sql_text) loop**

thanks.

Comment: show us the declaration for ora_name_list_t

Comment: It's  system defined event attributes in oracle.[ora_sql_txt(sql_text out ora_name_list_t)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg14evt.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That [function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#r25c1-t42) has an OUT parameter and returns a pls_integer number of elements. That document shows it being assigned to a variable:

```
    l_n := ora_sql_txt(l_sql_text);
    for i in 1..l_sql_text.count loop
```

So:

```
create or replace trigger aiud_employees_copy
  after insert or update or delete
  on employees_copy 
declare
    l_action employees_log.action%type;
    l_sql_text ora_name_list_t;
    l_n pls_integer;
begin
    l_action := 'The statement that causes the change was:' || chr(10);

    l_n := ora_sql_txt(l_sql_text);
    for i in 1..l_sql_text.count loop
        l_action := l_action || l_sql_text(i);
    end loop;
    insert into employees_log(who, action, when)
        values(user, l_action, sysdate);
end aiud_employees_copy;
/
```

... although referring to it directly should work.

But `ora_sql_txt()` is for system event triggers; for a DML trigger it will return null (apart from some versions of 9i, which seem to have been unintentional; see bug 4230721). The seciotn of the documentation the function is described in is ["Triggers for Publishing Events"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS2014), and it makes it clear that they only apply to certain database and client events.

> By invoking system-defined event attribute functions in Table 9-4, a trigger can retrieve certain attributes of the triggering event. Not all triggers can invoke all event attribute functions—for details, see ["Event Attribute Functions for Database Event Triggers"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#g1722284) and ["Event Attribute Functions for Client Event Triggers"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#g1722272).

So `ora_sql_txt(l_sql_text)` will be null, which is the value error you're getting. If you assign it to a variable first you'll still get an error. You can `nvl()` it to zero, but since it will always be null (and hence zero rows once you do that) it's a bit pointless.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
It's gives me the error:`ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection`

Comment: @zhanzezhu - you won't get a statement back for an update; it's for system events, not DML.